# Is it possible to pass JavaScript object to another PHP page and read by PHP functions?

Tags: javascript, php

I am using PHP and I have Javascript object called "row" in one page that contain some data and I know how to pass it to another page using `localStorage` but I wonder can I read this JS object using PHP functions in the second page ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store your object in cookie instead of localStorage.
Cookie can store only strings, so you should encode your object to string with javascript `JSON.stringify`, and then use `json_decode` to decode it in PHP.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript) how to set cookie with javascript.
Here's an example:

```
var data = {/*your data*/},
    string_data = JSON.stringify( data );

setCookie( 'my_data', string_data );
```

and then in PHP:

```
$data = json_decode( $_COOKIE[ 'my_data' ] );
```

Comment: error setCookie is not defined, please modify your example

Comment: I used `document.cookie`

Comment: `setCookie` is an abstract function to show the general idea

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
json_decode(string $json)
```

See documentation in http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php
This takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do?

PHP itself is not able to read js objects or variables, but you can pass them to php through post/get request via ajax (for example).

To pass a js object to php use json.

In [js](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
JSON.stringify(j);
```

in [php](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php):

```
json_decode(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

set `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` using javascript and retrieve values using javascript, no server code can directly access it.

Page1:

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
     localStorage.setItem("YourKey", "Your Value");
      //replace "Your Value" with 'row' object
} else {
      console.log("No Web Storage support..");
}

if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
     sessionStorage.setItem("YourKey", "Your Value");
     //replace "Your Value" with 'row' object
 } else {
      console.log("No Web Storage support..");
 }
```

Page2:

```
 if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
      localStorage.getItem("YourKey");
 } else {
      console.log("No Web Storage support..");
 }

 if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
      sessionStorage.getItem("YourKey");
 } else {
        console.log("No Web Storage support..");
 }
```

stringify `row` object using `JSON.stringify()` and send the value to php either through query string or cookies or form post.